# All Java Programs Crashing At Seemingly Random Points (Internal Error: Uncaught Exception)

Tags: java, macos

I just updated to the latest version of Java today (Java 8 Update 101)

Ever since, every time I try to run any Java program, it crashes with the following error:

**Error Message**

[image: Error Message]

Here's the content of the error:

```
Exception Name: JavaNativeException
Description: java.lang.NullPointerException

User Info: (null)

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb962952b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffcdd01cad objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb9629479 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   JavaNativeFoundation                0x000000010e7266d8 JNFCallObjectMethod + 230
4   liblwawt.dylib                      0x00000001101fa09e -[AWTView attributedSubstringForProposedRange:actualRange:] + 78
5   AppKit                              0x00007fffb7b70604 -[NSTextInputContext(NSInputContext_WithCompletion) attributedSubstringForProposedRange:completionHandler:] + 105
6   AppKit                              0x00007fffb7b6c6ec __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.625 + 91
7   AppKit                              0x00007fffb7b66e9a -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleTSMEvent_attributedSubstringForProposedRange_withContext:dispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:] + 92
8   AppKit                              0x00007fffb7b6c616 __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.620 + 450
9   AppKit                              0x00007fffb73cd760 -[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:] + 2549
10  AppKit                              0x00007fffb73cccfd _NSTSMEventHandler + 319
11  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8b190d5 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1708
12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8b18346 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 428
13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8b1818f SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 43
14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8b6ef86 SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 408
15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8d22378 __SendTextInputEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 584
16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8d20689 SendTextInputEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 1154
17  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8d91829 -[IMKInputSession _postEvent:completionHandler:] + 176
18  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8da1485 -[IMKInputSession _copyUniCharsForRange:intoBuffer:ofLength:completionHandler:] + 530
19  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8da1c0e -[IMKInputSession _coreAttributesFromRange:whichAttributes:completionHandler:] + 281
20  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8da3bb0 -[IMKInputSession attributedSubstringFromRange:completionHandler:] + 186
21  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8d943ab __61-[IMKInputSession imkxpc_attributedSubstringFromRange:reply:]_block_invoke + 530
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb95bf3ac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb95a0424 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb959ff66 __CFRunLoopRun + 1878
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb959f5b4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
26  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8b40f6c RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
27  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8b40da1 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
28  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffb8b40bd6 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
29  AppKit                              0x00007fffb72375f5 _DPSNextEvent + 1093
30  AppKit                              0x00007fffb79478eb -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1637
31  libosxapp.dylib                     0x00000001102974e3 -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
32  AppKit                              0x00007fffb722bfbd -[NSApplication run] + 926
33  libosxapp.dylib                     0x0000000110297346 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
34  liblwawt.dylib                      0x00000001101ed17d -[AWTStarter starter:] + 873
35  Foundation                          0x00007fffbafebf2a __NSThreadPerformPerform + 326
36  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb95bf551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
37  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb95a06bd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 557
38  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb959fbb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 934
39  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb959f5b4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
40  java                                0x000000010426e3b0 CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871
41  java                                0x0000000104268b5c JLI_Launch + 1952
42  java                                0x000000010426e70d main + 101
43  java                                0x00000001042683b4 start + 52
```

I have heard of other users having a similar problem, some recently and some in 2014, 2010, 2006, etc.

I have tried uninstalling Java using cmd, as well as editing the environmental variable, though I just copied and pasted what I found on the internet and didn't really understand what I was doing:

**Uninstall attempt/Environmental variable deletion attempt**

[image: Uninstall attempt/Environmental variable deletion attempt]

I found instructions for a solution involving deleting the environmental variable that seemed promising, but I don't know how to do them for mac (all I could find was what I pasted in terminal, as seen in the picture above)

Seemingly promising instructions:
youtube.com/watch?v=JF_o8WNt3hs&feature=youtu.be

I can't use any of my java based programs now, including netbeans, without them crashing within a few clicks. They all seem to crash at random points, but it's possible that the points at which they crash all have to do with writing data to the drive.

Comment: maybe you installed a JVM which is not compatible with your OSX?

Comment: Possibly - I just recently updated to Sierra. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Your terminal screenshot shows some clearly-wrong commands - the message `$: command not found` is telling you `$` is not a command. I'm guessing you copy-pasted those commands from somewhere, and erroneously included the `$` the author used to indicate the start of the prompt. Needless to say, that terminal screenshot is essentially gibberish.

Comment: It sounds like you're really asking (a) how can I uninstall the Java version I installed and (b) how can I properly upgrade Java on my Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the $, as for the Java update, at first even after upgrade and reboot it continued to fail, but after a couple of weeks it just went back to normal